# В функции $location.path, не дает закончить процесс удаления элемента из localStorage

Tags: angularjs

Заранее спасибо!

В template есть кнопка
`<a class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteNote()">Удалить</a>`
при клике на нее срабатывает метод из note-item.component.js

```
angular.module('noteItem').component('noteItem', {
  templateUrl: 'note-item/note-item.template.html',
  controller: ['$routeParams', '$localStorage', '$location', '$scope',
    function NoteItemController($routeParams, $localStorage, $location, $scope) {
      this.noteId = $routeParams.noteId;
      this.note = $localStorage.notes.find(note => note.id == this.noteId);
      $scope.storage = $localStorage;

      $scope.deleteNote = () => {
        $scope.storage.notes.splice($scope.storage.notes.indexOf(this.note), 1);
        $location.path = ('/notes');
      };

    }
  ]
});
```

Элемент не успевает удалиться, как срабатывает `$location.path = ('/notes');` и происходит редирект.
Как сделать так, чтобы `$location.path = ('/notes');` сработала, после того `$scope.storage.notes.splice($scope.storage.notes.indexOf(this.note), 1);` изменит localStorage

Получается добиться результата вот так, объясните пожалуйста, как это работает. Не так давно пришел в JS, спасибо.

```
$scope.deleteNote = () => {
        $localStorage.notes.splice($localStorage.notes.indexOf(this.note), 1);
        setTimeout(changeLocation, 500);
      };

      function changeLocation() {
        history.back();
      }
```

Comment: А что такое `$localStorage` ? Это не похоже на стандартный `localStorage`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko 
Использовал сторонний модуль для работы с localStorage:
https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

Comment: Читайте о вашей проблеме и способах решения в документации https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage#watch-the-watch. Там же и написано, почему это происходит.